# Entity framework The 'Week' property could not be mapped to the database type 'JSONB' because database provider doesn't support mapping to 'JSONB'

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, jsonb, poco

I am trying to use JsonB column using a POCO class in .NET core application using entity framework core 6.
I tried to create a database migration (add-migration "AddWeek") It gave me below exception in console

The 'Week' property "WeekData.Week" could not be mapped to the database type 'JSONB' because the database provider does not support mapping 'Week' properties to 'JSONB' columns.
Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter.
See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Entity class**

```
public class WeekData
{
    public Week? Week { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON POCO class**

```
public class Week
{
    public int[]? WeekDays { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity framework configuration ModelBuilder**

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WeekData> builder)
{
    builder.Property(jc => jc.Week)
    .HasColumnName("week")
    .HasColumnType("JSONB");
}
```

Comment: Shot in the dark - have you tried using "jsonb" lowercase?  All documentation/examples I've seen use lowercase.

Comment: @Moho let me try it out

Comment: @Moho Shouldn't matter, postgres is case-insensitive (unless you use quotes around identifiers)

Comment: You might want to consider [defining an `enum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145006/1048572) in the database

Comment: @Bergi actually I want to use a complex object which can have child objects and arrays

Comment: The migration worked! When I tried querying it gave error The LINQ expression 'DbSet<WeekData>()
    .Where(j => j.Week != null && j.Week.WeekDays
        .Contains(3))' could not be translated
@Bergi

Comment: @ManojSoma Yeah I guess the question is valid on its own, without an enum, the JSON approach should be doable as well. My guess would be that you need to change the `builer.Property` to return a JSON type instead of `WeekDays`, but I don't know any .net.

Comment: I guess we have the limitation of querying via complex objects https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco
I am thinking of going with the JsonDocument approach @Bergi